# can't setState in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I'm using Reactjs 16.10.2 to make Website. But I can't setState.

First I passed function as a props of a component:

```
  getStepFour = (data)=>{

      this.setState({
        tenCaThi:data.tenCaThi,
        ngayThi:data.ngayThi,
        gioBatDau:data.gioBatDau,
        gioKetKetThuc:data.gioKetKetThuc,
        phongThi:data.phongThi,
      });

      console.log('data receipt four: ', data);
      console.log('state after set: ', this.state.tenCaThi);
    }
```

```
<ChiaCaThi getStepFour={this.getStepFour}/>
```

Then I used it to get data in ChiaCathi like this:

```
componentWillUnmount = ()=>{

          const data = {
            tenCaThi:this.state.tenCaThi,
            ngayThi:this.state.ngayThi,
            gioBatDau:this.state.gioBatDau,
            gioKetKetThuc:this.state.gioKetKetThuc,
            phongThi:this.state.phongThi,
          }

          console.log('data in chiacathi: ', data)

          this.props.getStepFour(data);
      }
```

For some setState was not working. State after set is null.

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dftPb.png)https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAhdD.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `setState()` is asynchronous. According to the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) for state,

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later.

Furthermore,

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

If you wish to read more about why state isn't updated immediately, feel free to read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11527#issuecomment-360199710), it is pretty in depth when it comes to explaining it.