# Using react hooks

Tags: reactjs

While trying to understand React hooks, i wrote this small code:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App(props) {
  var [x, setX] = useState(0);

  function handleClick(e) {
    setX(x++);

    console.log(x);
  }

  return(<div className="App">
    <h3 className="h"> Welcome user, please press this button:</h3>   
    {x}
    <br/>
    <button className='button' onClick={handleClick}> Click </button>
  </div>);
}
```

I was expecting to get output `1 2 3 4 5 6...` in console whenever i press the button, but i got this weird output instead `1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6` .

Can someone explain why we get such output and how to fix it ?

Comment: I have answered a similar question some time ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59495222/cant-setstate-in-reactjs/59495252#59495252. Basically, setting of state is asynchronous, thats why logging the state right after `setX` might result in 'older' values.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting duplicated values with only one `console.log` in your code like this - are you sure you can reproduce your problem with the code listed? (and yes, neither modifying `x` nor `console.log` after `setX` do not make sense, but those are separate problems that wouldn't duplicate the output)

Comment: I also don't know how i got duplicated values, but when i tried Antoni's answer, the problem was fixed !
I will now try to understand more what caused that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying x with `x++` command and then setting it again. You need to do something like this in the handleClick function:

```
setX(x + 1);

console.log(x);
```

The reason is that `x++` is equivalent to `x = x + 1` not `x + 1`.

**Bonus tip**:

Use `const` instead of `var` so that the interpreter warns you about modifying an immutable value.

Comment: it does not make sense to console.log after `setX` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/58877875/1176601

Comment: yes, the `x` inside the `console.log` will print the previous value, you could save the `x+1` into a variable and print that, since `setX` is pretty much guaranteed to set the state

Comment: I just added console.log for debugging purpose, now i will delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a callback function to your `setX` function.

This will ensure, that while doing computations, you will always have the previous value within the callback.

This is because `setX` is an async function.

You can do like so :

```
  function handleClick(e) {
    setX(previousCount => previousCount + 1);
    console.log(x);
  }
```

Working implementation attached.

[image: Edit friendly-minsky-839d2]